# MySQL update based on main table data with cross table subquery

Tags: mysql, select, update, subquery

I have the following SELECT statement which I have **simplified** here. It actually takes 0.6s to run as it does some calculations based on two tables (table1 & table2).

```
SELECT 
    table1.id,table1.lat,table1.lon, 
    (SELECT id 
       FROM table2 
      WHERE latitude=table1.lat AND longitude=table1.lon 
      LIMIT 0,1) AS subqueryresult 
FROM 
    table1
```

Maybe this thread will even help me to improve my select. The two tables itself have **no** common ids.

What I intend to do is update every row of `table1` with the value received in `subqueryresult`. `subqueryresult` itself results out of a SELECT based on the main table data (`table1.lat` & `table1.lon`) and just uses `table2` as a reference.

Any idea how to achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the fact that two tables don't have `id`s in common does not mean you cannot join them. You can [`JOIN`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) two tables using *any* boolean expression. This can be `table1.id = table2.id`, but in can also be `table2.latitude = table1.lat AND table2.longitude = table1.latitude`.

Let's assume these are your tables:

```
SELECT * FROM table1;
```

```
id |       lat |       lon
-: | --------: | --------:
 1 | 41.390205 |  2.154007
 2 | 40.416775 | -3.703790
 3 | 41.979401 |  2.821426
 4 | 40.304665 | -3.723679
```

```
SELECT * FROM table2;
```

```
 id |  latitude | longitude
--: | --------: | --------:
101 | 41.390205 |  2.154007
102 | 40.416775 | -3.703790
103 | 41.979401 |  2.821426
124 | 43.262985 | -2.935013
```

We could perform your original query with a subquery, and get:

```
SELECT 
    table1.id, 
    table1.lat, 
    table1.lon, 
    (SELECT id 
       FROM table2 
      WHERE latitude=table1.lat AND longitude=table1.lon 
      LIMIT 0,1
    ) AS subqueryresult 
FROM 
    table1
```

```
id |       lat |       lon | subqueryresult
-: | --------: | --------: | -------------:
 1 | 41.390205 |  2.154007 |            101
 2 | 40.416775 | -3.703790 |            102
 3 | 41.979401 |  2.821426 |            103
 4 | 40.304665 | -3.723679 |           null
```

(Nearly) the same can be done with a `JOIN` through the following query:

```
SELECT
    table1.id, table1.lat, table1.lon, table2.id AS table2_id
FROM
    table1
    JOIN table2 ON table2.latitude = table1.lat AND table2.longitude = table1.lon
```

```
id |       lat |       lon | table2_id
-: | --------: | --------: | --------:
 1 | 41.390205 |  2.154007 |       101
 2 | 40.416775 | -3.703790 |       102
 3 | 41.979401 |  2.821426 |       103
```

(If you want to get the row with *no match* on table2, you can use [`LEFT JOIN`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) instead of `JOIN`).

---

If you want to `UPDATE` `table1.id` to be the same as `table2.id`, you can do so on **MySQL** by using:

```
UPDATE
    table1
    JOIN table2 ON table2.latitude = table1.lat AND table2.longitude = table1.lon
SET
    table1.id = table2.id

SELECT * FROM table1
```

```
 id |       lat |       lon
--: | --------: | --------:
  4 | 40.304665 | -3.723679
101 | 41.390205 |  2.154007
102 | 40.416775 | -3.703790
103 | 41.979401 |  2.821426
```

**Note** that this is *not* standard SQL, which does not allow to have a `JOIN` on this part of an `UPDATE`. If more than one matching row exists on `table2`, the value used for the `update` could be *any* of the matching ones.

The standard SQL way to do the same thing is:

```
UPDATE
    table1
SET
    id =         /* Your subquery! */ 
    (SELECT
        table2.id
    FROM
        table2 
    WHERE
            table2.latitude = table1.lat
        AND table2.longitude = table1.lon
    ORDER BY id     /* good to have a criterion to select id */
    LIMIT 1
    )
WHERE
    EXISTS     /* The subquery actually returns something */      
    (SELECT 
         table2.id
    FROM
        table2 
    WHERE
            table2.latitude = table1.lat
        AND table2.longitude = table1.lon
    ) ;
```

Or:

```
-- Standard SQL
UPDATE
    table1
SET
    id = coalesce(
        (SELECT
            table2.id
        FROM
            table2 
        WHERE
                table2.latitude = table1.lat
            AND table2.longitude = table1.lon
        ORDER BY id
        LIMIT 1
        ), table1.id
    ) ;
```

You can check everything at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=19e76e91e6ce969118b1d9ce21947c4c)*

Comment: Thank you very much for the informative answer. The queries work as promised. However, if I run those on "large" table with both having more than 20000 entries it doesn't. Be reminded that my WHERE clause is much more complex. I don't really just compare those values, I calculate with them (I have to find the closest latitude/longitude from table2 based on the lat/lon from table1 for every row in table1) . I just didn't add it here for complexity reasons. I have changed your fiddle to what I tried so far. http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=28ad1ed1d3c23984129af6a5a7663939

Comment: You probably need to make some *spatial* indexes to find closer (lat, lng) points. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-spatial-indexes.html. I don't have much experience using them with MySQL. See also [Fast nearest-location finder for SQL](https://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/haversine-mysql-nearest-loc/) and [latitude/longitude find nearest latitude/longitude - complex sql or complex calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234204/latitude-longitude-find-nearest-latitude-longitude-complex-sql-or-complex-calc)

Comment: Finding the closest location is easy and even fast. Just combining it with the UPDATE doesn't work yet. I might have to use views to do it faster.